# Import VS project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, osx-snow-leopard, porting

I've a project made in VS2010 for windows using C++. Now I want to port it to MAC so that the code base remains constant as much as possible. I used QT for GUI for the same reason. But I couldn't find a simple way like import VS project along with project settings or some such thing in Xcode to get started quickly on mac part. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no convertor.

Alternative approach: You can use each IDE as a front-end for another tool, like CMake or qmake.

You could also try Qt Creator, Eclipse, or...